# Inner join with more than one OR conditions in spring boot

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I am using spring boot specification and trying to execute a query that looks like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.name
FROM
    partner p
        INNER JOIN
    detail d ON p.detail_id = d.id
        INNER JOIN
    account a ON d.account_id = a.id
        OR d.crm_id = a.top_parent
        OR d.crm_id = a.global_partner
```

I have used the code

```
  Join<Partner, Detail> details = root.join("detail");
  Join<Detail, Account> account = details.join("account");
  Predicate global = cb.equal(details.get("crm_id "), account.get("top_parent"));
  Predicate top = cb.equal(details.get("crm_id "), account.get("global_partner"));
  account.on(cb.or(global, top));
```

However, it creates the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.name
FROM
    partner p
        INNER JOIN
    detail d ON p.detail_id = d.id
        INNER JOIN
    account a ON d.account_id = a.id
        AND (d.crm_id = a.top_parent
        OR d.crm_id = a.global_partner)
```

Notice the AND operator in the query...I need to replace it OR operator

### Another use case I am struggling with

```
@Entity
public class Detail {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "detail", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Skill> skills;
}
```

I am trying to generate the query below using specifications

```
order by (select count(s.detail_id) from skill s where detail.id = s.detail_id AND s.category is not null) desc
```

I have used the code below

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.size(details.get("skills"))));
```

But the query it generates is

```
order by (select count(s.detail_id) from skill s where detail.id = s.detail_id) desc
```

Notice that I am unable to add an extra AND to the order by clause

Comment: You should consider using @tremendous7 solution as replacing the AND by OR would lead to a full table scan and filtering afterwards. This will lead to a poor performance because of the full table scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can not change that AND.
could you change the query in the following way

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name
FROM partner p INNER JOIN detail d ON p.detail_id = d.id, account a
where d.account_id = a.id
OR d.crm_id = a.top_parent
OR d.crm_id = a.global_partner
```

and the jpa criteria similar to

```
    Join<Partner, Detail> details = root.join("detail");
    Root<Account> account = criteria.from(Account.class);
    Predicate global = cb.equal(details.get("crm_id"), account.get("top_parent"));
    Predicate top = cb.equal(details.get("crm_id"), account.get("global_partner"));
    Predicate byId = cb.equal(details.get("account").get("id"), account.get("id"));
    Predicate or = cb.or(global, top, byId);
    criteria.where(or);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, @tremendous7....I implemented the solution you provided and it worked. Have been struggling for 4 days on this.

Comment: I am stuck with another use-case where I need to have a subquery in order by clause. I struggled with it for a week. Later on, I got to know that JPA doesn't support subquery in order by clause... would you be kind enough to suggest any workaround?

Comment: @Tapan do you have a small example query of what you need?

Comment: Thanks, @tremendous7...I was unable to add the details in the comment. So have updated my post with another use case I was struggling with.

Comment: @Tapan I'll throw a couple ideas: can you have a redundant persistent property for the count of skills with not null strategy inside Detail? if you can you could sort by that property. otherwise if your Skill contains a Detail reference could you select the other way around: select count(skill.id), skill.detail from Skill where skill.strategy is not null group by skill.detail order by count(skill.id) desc ? otherwise could you do the sorting in java?

Comment: doh don't mind the last suggestion, to sort in java you would need to fetch all the Skills just for sorting purposes.

Comment: Thanks @tremendous7....the first suggestions could work for me. I will give it a try.